# Displaying the JSON value

Tags: php, json

I would like to ask on how you can parse this in PHP and return the value as string.

this is the given JSON

```
{
"SOAP:Header": [],
"SOAP:Body": {
    "rfc:ZFI_MVIS_ASSET_MASTER.Response": {
        "ZMVISASSET": {
            "item": [
                {
                    "BUSINESS_UNIT": "123",
                    "KFZKZ": "xxx123",
                    "NAME": "lastname, firstname  middle"
                },
            ]
         }
    }
}
```

}

so basically I want get the BUSINESS_UNIT and NAME from the JSON and echo it on the page.

tried this but did not get the value and response error.

```
echo $res->SOAP:Body->rfc:ZFI_MVIS_ASSET_MASTER.Response->ZMVISASSET->item->BUSINESS_UNIT;
```

Comment: Hello You might try json_decode in php

Comment: json_decode, but dot forget that json_decode have a second param, false by default that determine if to parse the string into std objects or to array

Comment: thanks guys i did solve it already.

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" or similar to your title. Instead, please [accept the answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that helped you the most. (If you found the answer yourself, you can even [self answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.) If you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) any answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
?>
```

Output

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```